# Pandas rolling window on an offset between 4 and 2 weeks in the past

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, window

I have a datafile with quality scores from different suppliers over a time range of 3 years. The end goal is to use machine learning to predict the quality label (good or bad) of a shipment based on supplier information.

I want to use the mean historic quality data over a specific period of time as an input feature in this model by using pandas rolling window. the problem with this method is that pandas only allows you to create a window from t=0-x until t=0 for you rolling window as presented below:

```
df['average_score t-2w'] =  df['score'].rolling(window='14d',closed='left').mean()
```

And this is were the problem comes in. For my feature I want to use quality data from a period of 2 weeks, but these 2 weeks are not the 2 weeks before the corresponding shipment, but of 2 weeks, starting from t=-4weeks , and ending on t=-2weeks.
You would imagine that this could be solved by using the same string of code but changing the window as presented below:

```
df['average_score t-2w'] =  df['score'].rolling(window='28d' - '14d',closed='left').mean()
```

This, or any other type of denotation of this specific window does not seem to work.

It seems like pandas does not offer a solution to this problem, so we made a work around it with the following solution:

```
def time_shift_week(df):
    def _avg_score_interval_func(series):
        current_time = series.index[-1]
        result = series[(series.index > ( current_time- pd.Timedelta(value=4, unit='w'))) 
                        & (series.index < (current_time - pd.Timedelta(value=2, unit='w')))]
        return result.mean() if len(result)>0 else 0.0
    temp_df = df.groupby(by=["supplier", "timestamp"], as_index=False).aggregate({"score": np.mean}).set_index('timestamp')
    temp_df["w-42"] = (
        temp_df
        .groupby(["supplier"])
        .ag_score
        .apply(lambda x: 
            x
            .rolling(window='30D', closed='both')
            .apply(_avg_score_interval_func)
    ))
    return temp_df.reset_index()
```

This results in a new df in which we find the average score score per supplier per timestamp, which we can subsequently merge with the original data frame to obtain the new feature.
Doing it this way seems really cumbersome and overly complicated for the task I am trying to perform. Eventhough we have found a workaround, I am wondering if there is an easier method of doing this.

Is anyone aware of a less complicated way of performing this rolling window feature extraction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While pandas does not have the custom date offset you need, calculating the mean is pretty simple: it's just sum divided by count. You can subtract the 14-day rolling window from the 28-day rolling window:

```py
# Some sample data. All scores are sequential for easy verification
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [list("ABC"), pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2022-12-31")],
    names=["supplier", "timestamp"],
)

df = pd.DataFrame({"score": np.arange(len(idx))}, index=idx).reset_index()

# Now we gonna do rolling avg on score with the custom window.
# closed=left mean the current row will be excluded from the window.
score = df.set_index("timestamp").groupby("supplier")["score"]
r28 = score.rolling("28d", closed="left")
r14 = score.rolling("14d", closed="left")

avg_score = (r28.sum() - r14.sum()) / (r28.count() - r14.count())
```